# Create new directory in share-point using SOAP in java

Tags: java, soap

I have just started working on share-point using java my firm uses share-point 2010 version so I have to work using SOAP and I have done following functionality.

Download Document from share-point.

Upload Document to share-point.

But I am stuck at creating new directory, I have tried some code by googling but no luck.
Here is my code:

```
public void createFolder(ListsSoap ls, String filePathToCreate,
            String fileName, LoginDO loginDO, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {
        try {
            String query = "";
            String folderName = "NewFolder";
            // 1. Prepare Query, Query Options and field Options
            if (CommonUtilities.isValidStr(folderName)) {
                // Prepare Query & Query Options for child folders
```

query = "<Batch OnError=\"Continue\" PreCalc=\"TRUE\" ListVersion=\"0\" " +
                    "RootFolder=\"https://xxx/Shared%20Documents/FPL%20SOs%20-%20JD%20Documents\">"
                    + "<Method ID=\"1\" Cmd=\"New\">"
                    + "<Field Name=\"FSObjType\">1</Field>"
                    +"<Field Name=\"ID\">New</Field>"
                    + "<Field Name=\"BaseName\">" + folderName + "</Field>"
                    + "</Method></Batch>";
        } else {
            // Prepare Query & Query Options for Parent folders

            query = "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"FSObjType\" />"
                    + "<Value Type=\"Lookup\">1</Value></Eq></Where></Query>";

        }

        UpdateListItems.Updates updates = null;

        // 2. Prepare Query, QueryOptions & ViewFields object as per options
        if (CommonUtilities.isValidStr(query)) {
            updates = new UpdateListItems.Updates();
            updates.getContent().add(
                    sharepointUtil.createSharePointCAMLNode(query));
        }

        // 3. Call Web service to get result for selected options
        UpdateListItemsResult result = ls
                .updateListItems(SHAREPOINT_FOLDER_NAME,updates);

        /*
         * CommonUtilities
         * .getApplicationProperty(ApplicationConstants.SHAREPOINT_FOLDER_NAME
         * ), "", msQuery, viewFields, "", msQueryOptions, "");
         */
        // 4. Get elements from share point result
        Element element = (Element) result.getContent().get(0);
        NodeList nl = element.getElementsByTagName("z:row");
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            Node node = nl.item(i);
            System.out.println("Some.!");

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // logger.logMethodEnd();
}`

**Anyhow updateListItems() method is executed without error but there is nothing in result.**

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you :)

Comment: Maybe this helps http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/50997/how-to-create-a-folder-in-sharepoint-2010-document-library-using-rest-or-http-me

Answer (score 0):

seems there was problem in

```
"RootFolder=\"https://xxx/Shared%20Documents/FPL%20SOs%20-%20JD%20Documents\">"
```

while passing root directory to create folder within.
found other way around by passing folderName with full directories hierarchy.

Thank you all for your inputs :)